# Decoding a struct using a key from JSON swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Using Swift 4's `Encoder` & `Decoder` protocol and `JSONDecoder` how do I initialize a struct of type `Codeable` using a key from a given JSON.

i.e. Given the JSON below I wish to only use `results` to initialize `Example`

```
{
  "boolean": true,
  "number": 123,
  "results": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
struct Example: MDB, Codeable{
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: String
}
public static func initalize<T: Codable & MDBItem>(json: Data) -> [T]{
        var items = [T]()
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
         //How do I initialize `T` using a key from the JSON given
          //ie. decoder.decode([T].self, from: json["results"])
          // Or decoder.decode(["results", [T].self, from: json)
            items = try decoder.decode([T].self, from: json)
                    } catch {
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        }
        return items
    }
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44549310/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/44715494/2976878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible easy way is creating a wrapper struct.

So, you have this JSON

```
let json = """
    {
    "boolean": true,
    "number": 123,
    "results": {
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d",
        "e": "f"
    },
    "string": "Hello World"
    }
    """
```

Since you are only interested into the `"results"` section you defined this struct

```
struct Example: Codable {
    let a: String
    let c: String
    let e: String
}
```

### Wrapper

Now in order to leverage the power of the `Codable` protocol (available in Swift 4) you can create a wrapper struct like this

```
struct Wrapper: Codable {
    let results: Example
}
```

> The only purpose of the Wrapper struct is to define a path from the root of the original JSON to the section you are interested in. This was the `Codable` protocol will do the rest of the job for you.

### Decoding

Now you can use the Wrapper struct to easily decode the JSON.

```
if
    let data = json.data(using: .utf8),
    let wrapper = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Wrapper.self, from: data) {

    let results = wrapper.results
    print(results)
}
```

And finally you can extract the `results` property from the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this should work. I'll just have to figure out a generic way to make it work with multiple structs.