# Wrapping Keys Decodable avoid struct

Tags: json, swift, parsing, decodable

In my current project when using Decodable we have the problem of models that look like this:

```
{
    "beers": [ {...} ]
}
```

the solution to solve this is to have something like this:

```
struct BeerList : Codable {
   let beers: [Beer]
}
```

My question is there way to parse this avoid this BeerList Struct ? And simply return an array of [Beer].

BTW the example I'm giving here is not the real one you can also find it here https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723563/1801544 ?

Comment: it's similar but the root node is matching the type inside the array. ex. beers != Beer

Comment: In your link, there is the part "Customizing Key Names" where you can for instance use your own "variable names", but tell the the decoder that it correspond to a different key name. I guess it could work.

Comment: But how would you avoid the struct? Because the Keys can be customised inside the struct.

Comment: You can customize (almost) everything, but the more custom the more code to write, in this case you have to specify CodingKeys and write an initializer. You get the  magic of `Codable` (no extra code) only if the structs match exactly the JSON